# How many different class template permutations are there in the standard library?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Let's say I want to do something contrived like this:

```
template<typename T, template <typename, typename> class Cont>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Cont<T, std::allocator<T>> cont)
{
    for (const auto& el : cont)
        std::cout << el << "\n";
    return os;
}

template<typename T, template <typename, typename> class Cont>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Cont<T, std::deque<T>> cont)
{
    while (!cont.empty())
    {
        std::cout << cont.top() << "\n";
        cont.pop();
    }
    return os;
}
```

I realize I can just do `std::vector<T>` and `std::stack<T>` but from what I understand, `deque` and `vector` for example have similar interfaces. The first overload will accept `deque`, `forward_list` and `vector`. So my question is, is there a simple list or graph that will tell me how many overloads I need?

Comment: Do you also want to support when, for example, you have a `std::stack<int, std::vector<int>>`? If so, then there are potentially infinitely many permutations, as container adapters can take any container type that has the necessary interface (including custom containers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard sequence containers are enumerated in § 23.3.1 [sequences.general]/1:

> The headers `<array>`, `<deque>`, `<forward_list>`, `<list>`, and `<vector>` define template classes that meet the requirements for sequence containers.

That said, I would prefer a generic solution using traits to detect types that are sequence-like and stack-like. I'll call anything a sequence that has members `begin` and `end` that return the same type:

```
template <bool B, typename T>
using enable_if =
  typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct is_sequence_helper {
  template <typename U=T>
  static auto test(int) ->
    enable_if<
      std::is_same<
        decltype(std::declval<U>().begin()),
        decltype(std::declval<U>().end())
      >::value,
      std::true_type
    >;

  template <typename U=T>
  static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;
};

template <typename T>
using is_sequence =
  decltype(is_sequence_helper<T>::test(0));
```

and we'll say anything with members `top`, `pop`, and `empty() const` is a stack:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_stack_helper {
  template <typename U=T>
  static auto test(int) ->
    decltype((std::declval<U>().top(),
              std::declval<U>().pop(),
              std::declval<const U>().empty(),
              std::true_type{}));

  template <typename U=T>
  static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;
};
template <typename T>
using is_stack =
  decltype(is_stack_helper<T>::test(0));
```

With these traits we can constrain your stream insertion operators more generically to work on sequences or stacks:

```
template<typename Sequence>
enable_if<
  is_sequence<Sequence>::value && !is_stack<Sequence>::value,
  std::ostream&
> operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Sequence& cont) {
  os << "sequence version:\n";
  for (const auto& el : cont)
    os << el << '\n';
  return os;
}

template<typename Stack>
enable_if<
  is_stack<Stack>::value,
  std::ostream&
> operator<<(std::ostream& os, Stack& cont) {
  os << "stack version:\n";
  for (; !cont.empty(); cont.pop())
    os << cont.top() << '\n';
  return os;
}
```

[See it all pulled together and working at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a81f704b9247c1bc).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I should've realized that they would be categorized like that.